# Enthought TraitsUI cursor won't update

Tags: python, cursor, enthought, traitsui

I've started developing an older project that was orphaned and needs to be updated a bit, and am having some issues with the TraitsUI trait input factories. If I use either RangeEditor or TextEditor, as I move from entry field to entry field the cursor will initially move between the fields the first time I select them, however if I try to reselect a field the cursor will not update position or field selection. I can only select the different fields with tab, however that's a nuisance.

I have a feeling this is tied to another issue [where the scrollbar position didn't update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20170628/python-traitsui-how-to-control-scrollbar-position-of-a-string-trait-editor-v?rq=1), however I haven't been able to resolve this.

Here is example code that causes the problem:
    from traits.api import HasTraits, Range
    from traitsui.api import Item, Group, View

```
class RangeEditorDemo(HasTraits):

    float_range = Range(0.0, 150.0)

    View1=View(Group(
        Item('float_range', style='simple', label='Top Simple'),
        Item('_'),
        Item('float_range', style='simple', label='Middle Simple'),
        Item('_'),
        Item('float_range', style='simple', label='Bottom Simple'),
        Item('_'),
        Item('float_range', style='custom', label='Custom'),
        Item('_'),
        Item('float_range', style='text', label='Text'),
        Item('_'),
    ))

demo = RangeEditorDemo()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    demo.configure_traits()
```

The package versions I'm using are:

```
Python 2.7.13
traits==4.4.0
traitsui==4.4.0
wxPython==3.0
```

Comment: Mike, it might also be useful to post your question in the newly revived ETS users group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ets-users